# Redefine Function to Solve Discontinuity

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

$$
f(x) = \frac{6x^2-5x-4}{2x^2+x}
$$

$f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = -1/2$
Redefine $f(-1/2)$ so that the discontinuity can be removed

Comment: $f$ is *not* discontinuous at $x=-1/2$; it is *undefined* at $x=-1/2$.

Comment: That leads it to have a "point discontinuity" does it not? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Some sources may use that terminology, but I'm not happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Away from $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}$ we have

$$ f(x) = \frac{6x^2-5x-4}{2x^2+x} = \frac{(2x+1)(3x-4)}{(2x+1)x} = \frac{3x-4}{x}; $$

therefore

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}} \frac{6x^2-5x-4}{2x^2+x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}} \frac{3x-4}{x} = \frac{-\frac{3}{2}-4}{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{-\frac{11}{2}}{-\frac{1}{2}} = 11. $$

Thus, we can simply redefine $f\big(-\tfrac{1}{2}\big)$ as 11, and $f(x)$ will be continuous at $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}$.

EDIT:  If the function is actually $f(x)=\tfrac{6x^2+5x-4}{2x^2+x}$, then

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}^+} \ f(x) = \infty $$

and

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}^-} \ f(x) = -\infty, $$

so there is no way to redefine the function so that it is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, hahaha I just figured out that while trying to solve it I had 6x^2+5x instead of 6x^2-5x, thanks a ton though!

Comment: Don't mention it.  :)

Comment: I added a comment about that situation, should you be interested.

Comment: that's why I freaked out about my graph at first hahaha